# When i wirte to file in R it always puts the values on a new line

Tags: r

when i write my vector to a file it always places it on a new line. How can I stop this. see my code below. Each variable in x is written to a new line.

```
x<- c(compname,mean(askspread),median(askspread),mean(q, na.rm=TRUE),median(q, na.rm=TRUE),max(q, na.rm=TRUE),timeticks,"\n")
write(x, file = "/testdata.txt",append=TRUE,sep = ",")
```

Comment: What would you like the output to be? I would recommend putting you data in a `data.frame` and using `write.csv` to write it to a file.

Comment: Use `cat()` instead, or change `ncolumns`

Comment: x <- paste(compname,mean(askspread),median(askspread),mean(q, na.rm=TRUE),median(q, na.rm=TRUE),max(q, na.rm=TRUE),timeticks,"\n", sep = ",")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x <- paste(compname,mean(askspread),median(askspread),mean(q, na.rm=TRUE),median(q, na.rm=TRUE),max(q, na.rm=TRUE),timeticks,"\n", sep = ",")
```